# Why do we need regularized logistic regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, regularization

We use regularized **Linear Regression** to prevent the model from overfitting (reduce model complexity).

Does the same idea hold with regularized **Logistic Regression**?

Is regularized Logistic Regression a solution to the problem of separation? if yes, how?

I am sure I had some misunderstanding, can anyone help to clarify that for me.

Answer (score 8):

> We use regularized Linear Regression to prevent the model from overfitting (reduce model complexity). Does the same idea hold with regularized Logistic Regression?

Yes. The bias-variance trade-off exists in all areas of statistics.

> Is regularized Logistic Regression a solution to the problem of separation?

Yes; even a small penalty on the coefficients will bound them away from infinity. This is because you will not be able to improve model fit to be arbitrarily good without eventually trading-off with an increase in penalty on coefficients.

See also: [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: how does the regularized Logistic Regression solve the problem of separation?

Comment: What does it mean to be "solved"? What part of my explanation is unclear?

Comment: you said yes regularized Logistic Regression is a solution to the problem of separation, how does this work, how this regularized regression solves this problem.

Comment: Did you read the next sentence?

Comment: yes I did read it..

Comment: Write down the logistic regression loss with an $L^2$ penalty. What happens as the coefficients get arbitrarily large in absolute value?

Comment: @jeza https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401212/showing-the-equivalence-between-the-l-2-norm-regularized-regression-and could be helpful