# Why standardization of design matrix $X$ with factor $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n-1}$ in lasso/glmnet?

Tags: standard-deviation, lasso, regularization, standardization, glmnet

I'm a little bit puzzled by the default standardization of the lasso/elastic net/ridge regression algorithms implemented in the (great!) glmnet package.

In most other applications, people would standardize a data matrix $X$ by centering all columns $j$ around the mean ($\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}=0$) and scaling columns to unit variance, meaning:

$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}^2=1$. (a)

In the original [glmnet](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/glmnet.pdf) and [lasso](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346178?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) papers, they state instead a normalization with factor $\frac{1}{n}$, that is, the *biased* estimator of the variance:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}^2=1$. (b)

The original [ridge regression](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~hzhang/math574m/Read/RidgeRegressionBiasedEstimationForNonorthogonalProblems.pdf) paper, on the other hand, states that $X^TX$ should have $1$s on the diagonal like a correlation matrix, leading to

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}^2=1$, (c)

without any multiplying factor. Now comes the most puzzling part, checking the [Fortran code of the glmnet package in R](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/src/glmnet5dp.f) (see lines 116 to 140), I cannot shake the feeling that they are actually standardizing such that:

$\frac{n}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}^2=1$, (d)

leading to the entries of the diagonal of $X^TX$ being just a little bit below $1$.

Now, I'm not fit in Fortran and I might read something wrong, but I've got two open questions now:

1. Why do they use the biased estimate of the variance/standard deviation for standardization in glmnet?
2. Or do they actually use the standardization with $\frac{n}{n-1}$?

The standardization in 2.) would actually make sense, since the diagonal of $X^TX$ would not depend on the number of observations anymore.

Comment: Why does it matter?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117369/connection-between-lasso-formulations suggests it does not.

Comment: Is diferent scaling of the matrix $X$ equivalent to different scalings of the loss function/lambda? I don't see it to be obvious if this is indeed the case...

Comment: Just multiply the entire objective function by any constant you want: it won't change any of the solutions.  Thus, the *only* thing that might matter is the ratio between the normalization coefficients of the design matrix and the multiplier of the penalty.  But the link I gave explains why even that doesn't matter (except for comparing solutions based on different conventions).

Comment: I get the first part of your comment, but I don't see the immediate connection to the normalized design matrix. Anyhow, I'm now quite convinced that scaling X by a factor c will lead to some scaling of lambda but won't change the solution, I will try to work this out myself

Comment: Could you tell me why they standardize the variables with the (1/N) variance estimator formula in `glmnet` package? Is it to mimic the MLE of the variance? If I use `scale()` function in `R` to standardize the variables by the 1/(N-1) formula, input the standadized data and use option `standardize=FALSE`, the de-standardized coefficients will be slight different from what the default method (input data in original scale with `standardize=TRUE`) would produce. I'm wondering if it is theoretically okay to use `scale` to standardize the data first and use them as the inputs. Could anyone help?

Comment: yes, it is ok. the coefficients/lambda values won't be the same if you use 1/n or 1/(n-1), but they are equivalent and can be transformed into each other. see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@whuber's comments led me to the solution: Yes, it doesn't matter. Scaling of the design matrix by a constant does not change the underlying optimization problem.

More precisely:

Suppose we are given some data matrix $X_0$ and a scaled design matrix $X=c\cdot X_0$, where $c>0$ is some real constant. E.g. $X_0$ could be such that (c) holds: $X_0^TX_0$ has $1$s on the diagonal, and with $c=\sqrt{1/n}$ we have $X$ such that (b) holds.

The glmnet optimization problem for $X_0$ would be to find the $\beta_0$ that minimizes $||y-X_0\beta_0||_2^2+\lambda_0||\beta_0||_p$, where $p$ is either $1$ (lasso) or $2$ (ridge). Elastic net is a combination of lasso and ridge, so I'm pretty sure the next step holds true anyway.

We have now the following:
$$
||y-X_0\beta_0||_2^2+\lambda_0||\beta_0||_p\\
= ||y-cX_0\cdot \frac{\beta_0}{c}||_2^2+\lambda_0c||\frac{\beta_0}{c}||_p\\
= ||y-X\beta||_2^2+\lambda||\beta||_p
$$
where $\lambda=\lambda_0\cdot c$ and $\beta=\beta_0/c$. That means the optimization problem is the same for both $X_0$ and $X$, but the lambdas and betas will live on a different scale. The solution for either $X_0$ or $X$ is equivalent to the solution for the other one.